# How to change Laravel Sanctum url prefix?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-sanctum

How could I change Laravel sanctum csrf cookie route to ***/api/sanctum/csrf-cookie*** ?

I tried the following change:

**config/sanctum**

```
'middleware' => [
        'verify_csrf_token' => App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        'encrypt_cookies' => App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
],

'prefix' => 'api'
```

But it doesn't work. What to do ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 7):

You were close! You also have to append to the prefix  the 'sanctum' part. Changing the `prefix` to `api` makes the route available at **/api/csrf-cookie**.

To realize what you want to do, just change `'prefix'` in the sanctum `config/sanctum.php` configuration file setting the route as follows `'prefix' => 'api/sanctum'`.

To verify that the route is available where it supposed to be, you can use the artisan command `php artisan route:list`

#### Reference:

https://github.com/laravel/sanctum/blob/2.x/src/SanctumServiceProvider.php#L81